# Python - Need to get last date for each ID in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Probably this is easy, but I'm new in Pandas:
I have DataFrame consists of "id" (int64) and "datetime" (datetime64):

```
d = {'id' : Series([1., 2., 3., 2., 3., 1., 1., 3., 1., 2.]), 
'datetime' : Series(['01.02.2015', '01.02.2015', 
'01.03.2015', '03.01.2015', '06.02.2015', '01.04.2015', '18.03.2015', 
'02.02.2015', '03.02.2015', '02.04.2015'])}

df = DataFrame(d)

df["datetime"] = to_datetime(df["datetime"], dayfirst=True)

print(df)
```

I need to get new DataFrame with unique "id" and last appropriate "datetime". In other words, I want to get something like this:

```
Out:
             datetime  id
0 2015-04-01 00:00:00   1
1 2015-04-02 00:00:00   2
2 2015-03-01 00:00:00   3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort) on 'datetime' and then call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) with param `take_last=True`:

```
In [135]:
df.sort(columns=['datetime']).drop_duplicates(subset='id', take_last=True)

Out[135]:
    datetime  id
2 2015-03-01   3
5 2015-04-01   1
9 2015-04-02   2
```

**Update**

[`sort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0181-deprecations) is now deprecated since `0.18.1`, you need to use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values):

```
df.sort_values(by=['datetime']).drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last')
```

Comment: Nice follow up bro!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.sort_values(by='datetime').drop_duplicates(subset='id', keep='last')
```